# Adding date using moment timezone but not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, moment-timezone

```
if (updatedFormElement.elementType === "date") {
                updatedFormElement.value = moment(formData[key]).tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                updatedFormElement.form_value = moment(formData[key]).tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                if (updatedFormElement.value === "Invalid Date") {
                    updatedFormElement.value = "";
                    updatedFormElement.form_value = "";
                }
            }
```

the value of

```
formData[key] is
"2019-11-05T00:00:00.000Z"
```

now I want to achieve Now I want to convert it to los angeles time or maybe any region time, I'm trying the above code but it failing the component in react. What possibly I am doing wrong?

Comment: if you are using react why are you not using setState and setting inputs directly?

Comment: first check date type then format it

Comment: @epascarellocan you suggest how?